# Binding more than one 'id' to On click of body tag and to perform actions depending on the button clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bind, click

I am developing a hotel application in mvc4 with the help of razor and jquery. And in my app, I am trying to bind a click event to 2 buttons in my page and do appropriate action based on the button clicked. But my problem, how do i check which button is clicked? I **have id's for both buttons.** I tried,

**[Jquery Find which button is clicked then run a specific If else statement? (Newbie)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11742097/jquery-find-which-button-is-clicked-then-run-a-specific-if-else-statement-newb)**

but no luck because I have used the body tag to bind both buttons to the click event like,

```
    $("body").on("click","#Room1, #Room2", function (e) {
    if (counter> 0) {
    //stmts
    //stmts
    if ($('#Room1').data('clicked', true))
    //stmts
    }
    else {
    if ($('#Room2').data('clicked', true))
    {
    //stmts
    alert('Room1 clicked');
    }
    else
    {
    //stmts
    alert('Room2  clicked');
    }
    //stmts
    //stmts
    }
    });
```

(ie).,for both the buttons, I'm binding to the same click because i have few common stmts to be performed. But have to check if particular button is clicked and perform few other operations.

I can bind them seperately and define the handlers separately, but just that they have a few common operations and **I dont want to repeat the code.**

Can someone please help me? I am sure there are a bunch of jquery experts out there..

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Are the buttons added dynamically here??

Comment: No @palash. They are always present within the body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually very simple. When you use event delegation with the [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on) method, the context of the event handler will be the delegated element. That is to say, it will be the element matched by the `"#Room1, #Room2"` selector. In very simple terms, within the event handler `this` will point to either the `#Room1` or the `#Room2` element.

You can then check `this.id` to determine which element was clicked.

```
$(document.body).on("click","#Room1, #Room2", function (e) {
    alert(this.id + ' was clicked');

    // common code

    if (this.id === 'Room1') {
        // #Room1 code
    }

    if (this.id === 'Room2') {
        // #Room2 code
    }
});
```

Comment: Excellent !! this was what I wanted exaclty...!